# Calculating grammar similarity between two sentences

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

I'm making a program which provides some english sentences which user has to learn more.

For example:

> First, I provide a sentence *"I have to go school today"* to user.
>   Then if the user wants to learn more sentences like that, I find some sentences which have high grammar similarity with that sentence.

I think the only way for providing sentences is to calculate similarity.

Is there a way to calculate grammar similarity between two sentences?

or is there a better way to make that algorithm?

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach for solving this problem would be to do a **Part Of Speech Tagging** of using a tool like [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) and compare the trees structure of your phrase with your database.

Other way, if you already have a training dataset, use the [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) to use a machine learn approach to connect the phrases.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your sentence as either a constituent or dependency tree and use these representations to formulate some form of query that you can use to find candidate sentences with similar structures.

You can check this available tool from [Stanford NLP](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.shtml):

> Tregex is a utility for matching patterns in trees, based on tree relationships and regular expression matches on nodes (the name is short for "tree regular expressions"). Tregex comes with Tsurgeon, a tree transformation language. Also included from version 2.0 on is a similar package which operates on dependency graphs (class SemanticGraph, called semgrex.

Comment: is there any paper or any one already did build deep learning model using grammar generated from parse tree or even using parse tree as training data?